# Basic use of functions in python

Tags: python, function, methods

I'm trying to learn Python 3. This is an example I am trying to learn from. So here I define a function to read text. Open a file, read the contents, print it, then close.

So this code runs well. The thing I don't understand, however, is why we write:

print(contents_of_file), but not read(quotes). How come it's quotes.read()? As far I can understand both print() and read() are functions and I expected both to be used the same way. What am I missing here - please help?

Is there a rule when to put stuff inside brackets and when not to?

```
def read_text():
    quotes = open("/Users/me/text.txt", encoding = "utf-8")
    contents_of_file = quotes.read()
    print(contents_of_file)
    quotes.close()
read_text()
```

Comment: http://effbot.org/pyfaq/why-does-python-use-methods-for-some-functionality-e-g-list-index-but-functions-for-other-e-g-len-list.htm

Comment: You can't say `read(quotes)` but you can say `io.TextIOWrapper.read(quotes)`, however you'll now also have to `import io`. But why would you want to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`print()` is a function. `read()` is a [**method** of the object](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html) bound to `quotes`. As such, `read` must be referred to by accessing `quotes`. Only then can we add parens to invoke it.

Comment: That was very helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You've stumbled across the often argued definitions of functions and methods.

`read()` is a method that belongs to `quotes` (which is an instance of a class, I don't actually know the name of which).  Technically, *Methods* belong to *Objects*, *Functions* are normally defined in a style that isn't strictly Object Orientated, or in global scope (like all C functions).

It might be worth reading up on the OOP aspects of Python, this will likely help you understand it more.

Comment: It's some descendant of `io.TextIOBase`, not that it really matters.

Comment: I'm sure I'll remember that in some strange, irrelevant moment in the future.

Answer (score 0):

`quotes` is a file object. I understand you don't yet know what is an object. But try printing `quotes`.

```
print type(quotes)
```

This object has a function `read()` whose purpose is to read contents from the file.

To call a function of an object, you have to write:

```
object.funcName()
```

As this is exactly what we want, we are just calling that function. So  we are writing:

```
quotes.read()
```

`print` doesn't belongs to any of these type of objects. So, we can call it without any object reference.